# Net FileSystemWatcher not running any more on Server 2008

Tags: filesystemwatcher

This is not directly a question about code, but FileSystemWatcher/OS behavior. I have an app, which monitors thousends of logfiles. The app
runs since years without any problems. It was running on a Server 2003 against shares hosted on Server 2003.

If it runs on Server 2008 (R2) and the store is on Server 2008 (R2) not much events are generated. I made a simple repro which show the difference [but as I told: The long running old proggi does work properly]. The apps, generating the logs are not under my code control.
In my repro - writing such log with pauses - even a flush for the writer and/or the underlaying stream does not help].

On Server 2003 each update [write operation from the logging app] causes the FSW to fire Size changed events. On Server 2008, this happens only, when the app starts to write the logfile and when the logfile closes. No events in the middle any more. Settings the REG keys to write NTFS timestamps brought no changes to this behavior.

I am not in a position to open a call at MS, but probably, someone has seen this behavior and knows a workaround.

The workaround coming to my mind are: Downgrade to Server 2003 or to Linux. Both works as expected.

Any ideas are really very welcome.

Best regards,

++mabra

[Net 2.0 => 4.0; No question: All patches, OS also]

[edit]

Sorry, there were faults in my analyzis .... Together with the move of my
app to Server 2008, a new app came to the set of files to monitor [Change
never two things at the same time....]. The new app has another behavior,
then the apps which's logs I've read before ....

(1)The old apps use: Open/append, write, close.
(2)The new app uses: Open/create, write, sleep, write, sleep, write, close.

The FSW gives me the changed event for the old apps behavior, but not
for the new one. The FSW Notifyfilters.Size does not work like I have
expected. So, the new app's log cannot be monitored with FSW.
I found no workaround to make the chnaged event fire for size changes
alone.

But this keeps: The is Windows Server 2008 ! Windows Server 2003 and
Linux with mono even gives you the changed event for (2) !!!!! So,
my "title" was not that bad ;-)

Unhappy with .Net now ....

If someone has probably an idea, please let me now !!

And sorry for my sloppy first-time analyzis ... ;-)

br,
++mabra

Comment: I've had this happen to an app we migrated to a new server. Did you ever get a resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the case, that someone is watching this ....

I opened an Issue at MS.Connect - some weeks ago - and they
directed it to the VS team.

The bad news are from today, where they first set the issue
to "Won't Fix" and then to close.

I see this as in indirect confirmation of a bug, which
will not be fixed.

I am completely disappointed.

Anyway, best regards,

++mabra

[=> MS Connect Issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/777417/notifyfilters-size-does-not-raise-events-on-server-2008-r2-windows-7)